# Browse for folder in C# VS2005

Tags: c#, asp.net, openfiledialog

I have a file format converter on my VS2005 using C#. Now my destination path is hard coded, and I would like to make it such that the user is able to browse for a path to store the output file.

I have googled and saw that I can use OpenFileDialog control in VS2005 toolbox under Dialogs. But I am not able to find that control in my VS2005.

I do not know if it is possible to save the filepath of the uploaded file, but I am able to save the file name and extension of the file that the user browses for.
E.g. Grep file name: string strFileName = Server.HtmlEncode(TextFile.FileName);
     Grep file extension: string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

I would like to ask 2 questions:

1. Is there an alternative for OpenFileDialog which I can use to browse for folders?
2. Is there a statement which is able to grep the filepath of the file like what I have did to grep the filename and file extension?

Thank You

Any alternatives which I can use?

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: FolderBrowserDialog.  Too obvious, did you lose that one too?

Comment: Using OpenFileDialog is very easy. Just make one programmatically, no need to get it from the toolbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`FolderBrowserDialog` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx).

If you're using WPF, you'll need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms, since WPF doesn't have its own version of this class.

If you're using ASP.Net, this is totally impossible, as is using a hard-coded path; you need to serve the file as a download.

---

You're also looking for `Path.GetDirectoryName`.

Comment: Hi SLaks, thank you for the useful information. I have tried string strPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName), but the string stored is empty. Do you have any idea why is it so? Thanks

Comment: **What platform**? Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: My psychic powers tell me you're using ASP.Net.  The browser doesn't send the path, so you can't see it.  You need to understand the basics of client-server programming and HTTP; you can't write to the user's disk.

Comment: Yea I'm using ASP.Net. So I am not able to retrieve directory for the file?

Comment: Correct.  You need to understand how the browser interacts with your code; your project will probably not work if the server is a different machine.

Comment: Yes my server is another machine. So I guess I will make a fixed path for it then. Thanks alot!